Unable to install odbc package on RStudio Pro - Posit Workbench
We have configured and installed RStudio Pro 2023.12.1 (Posit Workbench) software on our Azure Linux VM (Ubuntu) and now after logging into the software over chrome.
I wanted to connect to our Azure Datawarehouse service where I have our dataset and table present using the code below.
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                 Server = "sqldwserver.database.windows.net",
                 Database = "sqldwdb",
                 UID = "USER",
                 PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
                 Port = 1433)

But post running the code I am getting error as below,

Error in dbConnect(odbc(), Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
Server = "ucbsqldwserver.database.windows.net", : could not find
function "dbConnect"

When I tried to install the odbc package, I encountered the following error. Based on this error, I understand that the odbc package is not getting installed on the Linux vm, which is preventing me from making a connection.
I was able to run the above code on my Windows Azure VM where I have RStudio desktop free version installed, but I am encountering this error on my Post Workbench Web version which is installed on Linux VM.
Could you please help me fix this error as I have limited knowledge of both R and Linux OS?
Error for odbc package installation --
install.packages("odbc")
Installing package into ‘/home/rajP/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/odbc_1.5.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 299106 bytes (292 KB)
downloaded 292 KB

installing source package ‘odbc’ ...
** package ‘odbc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
PKG_CFLAGS=
PKG_LIBS=-lodbc
:1:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because odbc was not found. Try installing:
deb: unixodbc-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
rpm: unixODBC-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
csw: unixodbc_dev (Solaris)
pacman: unixodbc (Archlinux, Manjaro, etc)
brew: unixodbc (Mac OSX)
To use a custom odbc set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR and PKG_LIBS manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=... PKG_LIBS=...'
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘odbc’

removing ‘/home/rajP/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/odbc’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘odbc’ had non-zero exit status
The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpMHrTw7/downloaded_packages’


Looks like you may need to install and load the DBI package, which supplies the generic dbConnect() (for which odbc provides a method)!
So, replace:
library(odbc)

with:
library(odbc)
library(DBI)


I agree but they are not getting installed. I tried to install package but it fails with error as shared above.

The ANTICONF ERROR message,
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because odbc was not found. Try installing:
deb: unixodbc-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)

clearly refers to a system-level requirement, not an R package.
Since you're on a Ubuntu platform, press Ctrl + Alt + T to open a terminal. Then enter:
sudo apt update && sudo apt install unixodbc-dev

This installs the necessary system dependency. After that, in R install.packages("odbc") should work.
